# how do i get two value pairs from url using GET

Tags: php, redbean

Hie guys, i am writing a code to request a service from another page, when this page redirect to my site, below is the URL that it is returning to. But the problem now is i can only get one parameter which is the period_id.

https://leadingdigital.co.zw/maz/member/payments.php?ref=1538214143&period_id=3

```
    $reference = $_GET['ref'];
    $id = $_GET['period_id'];
```

i am getting my values via GET like that. But for me to then access my data using both values its not working. it only works when i remove the ref from the url. Is not suppose to be like, for code block that required the period_id once it gets the value from $id = $_GET['period_id']; it works and then for the block that needs $reference = $_GET['ref']; may fail.

because in my case it is failing in both blocks.
this is the block that needs value from $reference = $_GET['ref'];
if the reference is not null then the code below will execute

```
    if ($reference != null) {
        $info = R::findOne('paynowtransaction', 'WHERE reference = ?', [$reference]);
        require 'vendor/autoload.php';
        $url = $info->pollurl;
        $response = \Httpful\Request::post($url)->send();

        $stageone = explode('&', $response);
        $data = array();

        for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($stageone); $i++) {
            $item = explode('=', $stageone[$i]);
            $data[$item[0]] = $item[1];
        }
        $status = $data['status'];
        $paynowref = $data['paynowreference'];
        $email = $info->email;
        $amount = $data['amount'];
        $message = "<h4>Your Payment of " . $amount . " with reference " . $paynowref . " has been made. Your payment status is :" . $status . "</h4><br/>";
        $message .= "<h4>Thank your for doing business with us!</h4>";


        if ($status != null) {
            $update = R::findOne('paynowtransaction', 'WHERE reference = ?', [$reference]);
            $update->status = $status;
            $update->paynowreference = $paynowref;

            R::store($update);

            //now save from paynowtransaction to payments
            $payments = R::dispense('payments');
            $payments->payment_date = $update->payment_date;
            $payments->amount_invoiced = $update->amount_invoiced;
            $payments->amount_paid = $amount;
            $payments->period_id = $update->period_id;
            $payments->pop = $paynowref;
            $payments->payment_method = 3;
            $payments->member_id = $update->member_id;
            $id = R::store($payments);

            $period_balance = R::load('renewal', $update->period_id);
            $new_balance = $period_balance->balance - $update->amount_paid;
            $period_balance->balance = $new_balance;
            if ($new_balance > 0) {
                $period_balance->payment_status = 2;
            } else {
                $period_balance->payment_status = 1;
            }
            R::store($period_balance);

        }
    }
```

this is the block that needs value from $id = $_GET['period_id'];
if the $id has something it has to load data like the script below.
i have tried that and its not working, i have to first remove reference from url for it to work

```
$payment_period = R::load('renewal', $id);
```

Comment: If you call the page wit both parameters like that there shoudl be no reason why you cannot get the paraemters from $_GET. So I dont actually understand your question

Comment: have you got any htaccess `rewrite` rules in effect?